# Read/Write binary file with structure of fixed length

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I need to read/write file which as light as possible and with super-fast read and write access. In other words, I cannot use serialization or binary serialization. I have to be able to update a single records and seek in the file quickly.

Essentially, I need a file structure similar to what I would do in C/C++ (i.e. fixed size structure with a defined size that I can read/write on the file and allow me to seek in it). Any idea how to do that in C#?

Comment: I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935851/a-c-equivalent-of-cs-fread-file-i-o) about this a while ago....and its answered... :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [A C# equivalent of C's fread file i/o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935851/a-c-equivalent-of-cs-fread-file-i-o)

Comment: try a MemoryMappedFile maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you can't just use the `FileStream` or more generally the `Stream` class to accomplish this goal.  Both of these classes support seeking and reading the raw data from a file without any serialization necessary.  Is there a reason this doesn't work for your scenario?

Comment: I have a struct with a couple of int, long, double, and date. I want to be able to open the file and seek at the exact position of the 100th record. Would it be possible with the FileStream? If so, how?