# What is the C# / .net equivalent of writing binary data directly to a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, c

The exact structure of the struct is not important.

From what I gather the following c code is reading a "chunk" of binary data (equal to the size of the struct) and directly writing that to a struct (i.e first 32 bytes to name, next 2 bytes to attrib, etc).  Is there any equivelent in C# managed code?

Please provide a code snipet showing similar outcome.  To save time you can simplify the to only a few elements and assume the appropriate filestream type object is already initialized.

Note: I will be consuming an existing legacy data file so the formatting/packing of the existing data file is important.  I can't for example just use .net serialization / deserization because I will be processing legacy existing files (changing format is not feasible).

```
typedef struct _PDB 
{
   char name[32];
   unsigned short attrib;
   unsigned short version;
   unsigned int created;
   unsigned int modified;
   unsigned int backup;
   unsigned int modNum;
   unsigned int nextRecordListID;
   unsigned short numRecs;
} PDB;

void getFileType(FILE *in) 
{
   PDB p;
   fseek(in, 0, SEEK_SET);
   fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, in);
. . .
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that that code will break if you share files between machines with different endianess?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that but for this application it won't be an issue (all files are of a single format, created by a single legacy app, and on a single platform - Windows XP).

Comment: possible duplicate of [A C# equivalent of C's fread file i/o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935851/a-c-equivalent-of-cs-fread-file-i-o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're asking about the [StructLayoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=VS.100).aspx) and the [FieldOffsetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute(v=VS.100).aspx).

Example (snippet) from MSDN site:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public class MySystemTime 
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]public ushort wYear; 
   [FieldOffset(2)]public ushort wMonth;
   [FieldOffset(4)]public ushort wDayOfWeek; 
   [FieldOffset(6)]public ushort wDay; 
   [FieldOffset(8)]public ushort wHour; 
   [FieldOffset(10)]public ushort wMinute; 
   [FieldOffset(12)]public ushort wSecond; 
   [FieldOffset(14)]public ushort wMilliseconds; 
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that part makes sense so far.  Defining the physical structure of the struct.  So now how to a write to the struct directly.  The equivelent of this c line: "fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, in)"  Would I just read in x bytes and then cast that as the struct?

Comment: Either this or you use the BitConverter.Toxxx method field by field - most likely there is not a large difference performance wise, but it is easier to debug.

Comment: @theUnhandledException : C# does support unions (by overlapping fields using the same code as myermian shows), so you can just add a byte array to it.  The "proper" way to do it is probably with `Marshal`, though `BinaryFormatter` can be used for this purpose, too.  The latter will probably stuff in metadata, so then you'd need to use `BinaryFormatter` to read it.  Richard Taylor has an explanation of how to do this with `Marshal` [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/taylorrich/archive/2006/08/21/88665.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Marshalling, it is IMHO what you are looking for.

This link has an in-depth view of structs in C#:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

Additional info may be found at MSDN's Marshal Class documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx