# How to read byte blocks into struct

Tags: c#, .net, struct, filestream

I have this resource file which I need to process, wich packs a set of files.

First, the resource file lists all the files contained within, plus some other data, such as in this struct:

```
struct FileEntry{
     byte Value1;
     char Filename[12];
     byte Value2;
     byte FileOffset[3];
     float whatever;
}
```

So I would need to read blocks exactly this size.

I am using the Read function from FileStream, but how can I specify the size of the struct?
I used:

```
int sizeToRead = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Header));
```

and then pass this value to Read, but then I can only read a set of byte[] which I do not know how to convert into the specified values (well I do know how to get the single byte values... but not the rest of them).

Also I need to specify an unsafe context which I don't know whether it's correct or not...

It seems to me that reading byte streams is tougher than I thought in .NET :)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you indicate what language you're using?  I took a wild guess and added [tag:c#] to the tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A C# equivalent of C's fread file i/o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935851/a-c-equivalent-of-cs-fread-file-i-o)

Comment: Sorry about that, it was indeed C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming this is C#, I wouldn't create a struct as a FileEntry type. I would replace char[20] with strings and use a BinaryReader - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx to read individual fields. You must read the data in the same order as it was written.

Something like:

```
class FileEntry {
     byte Value1;
     char[] Filename;
     byte Value2;
     byte[] FileOffset;
     float whatever;
}

  using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("path"))) {
     var entry = new FileEntry {
        Value1 = reader.ReadByte(),
        Filename = reader.ReadChars(12) // would replace this with string
        FileOffset = reader.ReadBytes(3),
        whatever = reader.ReadFloat()           
     };
  }
```

If you insist having a struct, you should make your struct immutable and create a constructor with arguments for each of your field.

Comment: This worked like a charm. How would you "replace this with string"? Using ReadString() you can't specify a size, so it reads beyond the desired position.

Comment: Actually, the size of string is contained in the stream if it was written as a string before. From MSDN - "Reads a string from the current stream. The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring.aspx). However, then you also must use the BinaryWriter.Write(string) before that. You could construct a string using chars - "StringField = new string(reader.ReadChars(20));".

Answer (score 6):

If you can use unsafe code:

```
unsafe struct FileEntry{
     byte Value1;
     fixed char Filename[12];
     byte Value2;
     fixed byte FileOffset[3];
     float whatever;
}

public unsafe FileEntry Get(byte[] src)
{
     fixed(byte* pb = &src[0])
     {
         return *(FileEntry*)pb;
     } 
}
```

The fixed keyword embeds the array in the struct.  Since it is fixed, this *can* cause GC issues if you are constantly creating these and never letting them go.  Keep in mind that the constant sizes are the n*sizeof(t).  So the Filename[12] is allocating 24 bytes (each char is 2 bytes unicode) and FileOffset[3] is allocating 3 bytes.  This matters if you're not dealing with unicode data on disk.  I would recommend changing it to a byte[] and converting the struct to a usable class where you can convert the string.

If you can't use unsafe, you can do the whole BinaryReader approach:

```
public unsafe FileEntry Get(Stream src)
{
     FileEntry fe = new FileEntry();
     var br = new BinaryReader(src);
     fe.Value1 = br.ReadByte();
     ...
}
```

The unsafe way is nearly instant, far faster, especially when you're converting a lot of structs at once.  The question is do you want to use unsafe.  My recommendation is only use the unsafe method if you absolutely *need* the performance boost.

Comment: Probably would be smarter not to use unsafe then, since it's only small files where proessing rates would not be really noticeable.

Answer (score 3):

Base on [this article](http://www.matthew-long.com/2005/10/18/memory-pinning/), only I have made it generic, this is how to marshal the data directly to the struct. Very useful on longer data types.

```
public static T RawDataToObject<T>(byte[] rawData) where T : struct
{
    var pinnedRawData = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData,
                                       GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        // Get the address of the data array
        var pinnedRawDataPtr = pinnedRawData.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        // overlay the data type on top of the raw data
        return (T) Marshal.PtrToStructure(pinnedRawDataPtr, typeof(T));
    }
    finally
    {
        // must explicitly release
        pinnedRawData.Free();
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FileEntry
{
    public readonly byte Value1;

    //you may need to play around with this one
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
    public readonly string Filename;

    public readonly byte Value2;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public readonly byte[] FileOffset;

    public readonly float whatever;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data =;//from file stream or whatever;
    //usage
    FileEntry entry = RawDataToObject<FileEntry>(data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, strings are probably better read as `Byte[]`, and then retrieved using some method that converts it to `Char[]` and then to `String`. With some rudimentary "ascii-only" checking and classic end-on-0 c-string behaviour, that'd be something like `String filename = new String(filenameArr.TakeWhile(x => x != 0).Select(x => x < 128 ? Convert.ToChar(x) : '?').ToArray());`

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping your `FileStream` with a `BinaryReader` will give you dedicated `Read*()` methods for primitive types: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx

Out of my head, you could probably mark your `struct` with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` (to ensure proper representation in memory) and use a pointer in `unsafe` block to actually fill the struct C-style. Going `unsafe` is not recommended if you don't really need it (interop, heavy operations like image processing and so on) however.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer (it's been covered I think), but a specific note on the filename:

The `Char` type is probably not a one-byte thing in C#, since .Net characters are unicode, meaning they support character values far beyond 255, so interpreting your filename data as `Char[]` array will give problems. So the first step is definitely to read that as `Byte[12]`, not `Char[12]`.

A straight conversion from byte array to char array is also not advised, though, since in binary indices like this, filenames that are *shorter* than the allowed 12 characters will probably be padded with '00' bytes, so a straight conversion will result in a string that's always 12 characters long and might end on these zero-characters.

However, simply trimming these zeroes off is not advised, since reading systems for such data usually simply read up to the first encountered zero, and the data *behind* that in the array might actually contain garbage if the writing system doesn't bother to specifically clear its buffer with zeroes before putting the string into it. It's something a lot of programs don't bother doing, since they assume the reading system will only interpret the string up to the first zero anyway.

So, assuming this is indeed such a typical zero-terminated (C-style) string, saved in a one-byte-per-character text encoding (like ASCII, DOS-437 or Win-1252), the second step is to cut off the string on the first zero. You can easily do this with Linq's `TakeWhile` function. Then the third and final step is to convert the resulting byte array to string with whatever that one-byte-per-character text encoding it's written with happens to be:

```
public String StringFromCStringArray(Byte[] readData, Encoding encoding)
{
    return encoding.GetString(readData.TakeWhile(x => x != 0).ToArray());
}
```

As I said, the encoding will probably be something like pure ASCII, which can be accessed from `Encoding.ASCII`, standard US DOS encoding, which is `Encoding.GetEncoding(437)`, or Windows-1252, the standard US / western Europe Windows text encoding, which you can retrieve with `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")`.