# Visual Studio Debugging - Native Types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am currently developing an application to work with WAV files. I want to be able to display the information in the struct with its native type, but C# thinks of char as a 16 bit value.

The four bytes ChunkID0...3 are supposed to contain 'R' 'I' 'F' 'F'

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 12, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct RiffDescriptor
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte ChunkID_0;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte ChunkID_1;

    ...
}
```

I want the debugger to show the ChunkID as 'R' instead of 122.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you declare it as `char` then?

Comment: How are you mapping 122 into R?

Comment: @Jon C# states that a char is a 16 bit type. I want to keep the original type.

Comment: @JaradPar I believe that it is just outputting the value of the byte, not its ASCII representation (which is what I want)

Comment: In c# a byte is an 8 bit unsigned number, so you want be able to see it as a char.  The debugger will never be able to show it as a number. Besides, a char in c# is unicode, using 2 bytes to represent it. You could only take each byte and use `Encoding.Convert()`, but that won't happen in the debugger. You can only configure how the debugger shows objects, but not value types. You'd do it with `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute.

Comment: @JotaBe Thanks, I think I might make a class called cbyte that overrides bytes ToString method (if I can) and use Encoding.Convert() in there. I'll post my results

Comment: Have a look at DebuggerDisplayAttribute, which will allow you to see your cbyte class the way you want in the debugger window.

Comment: Figured it out. I'll post the answer in a bit, SO won't let me post answer for another 7 hours.

I used

       
 `[DebuggerDisplay("Format = {System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Format)}")]`

        `public byte[] Format;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [A C# equivalent of C's fread file i/o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935851/a-c-sharp-equivalent-of-cs-fread-file-i-o)

Comment: @HansPassant No, this is a completely different question

Comment: It is not actually. You can use the pinvoke plumbing to convert data in a file to a managed class or struct.  Which will allow you to declare the tag as *string*, the ideal data type.  It is entirely up to you to ignore that option, other SO users that land on this question might find it useful.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for it to come across like that. My question was more keeping the structure exactly as the original C structure, just displaying the information from the debugger in a specific way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RiffDescriptor
{
    public RiffDescriptor(BinaryReader b)
    {
        // Read the ChunkID - Should be RIFF
        ChunkID = b.ReadBytes(4);

        // Read the ChunkSize
        ChunkSize = b.ReadUInt32();

        // Read the Format - Should be WAVE
        Format = b.ReadBytes(4);
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("ChunkID = {System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ChunkID)}")]
    public byte[] ChunkID;

    public UInt32 ChunkSize;

    [DebuggerDisplay("Format = {System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Format)}")]
    public byte[] Format;
}
```