# Marshal method to create an instance of a formatted type?

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, low-level

Is there any Marshal method which instantiate a formatted ready-to-use object?

By "formatted" I mean a struct that have its layout formatted with attributes like StructLayout and MarshalAs.

Some code to clarification bellow.

```
public struct s1
{
    public int i1;
    public int i2;
}

public struct s2
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
    public s1[] _s1;
}
```

What I want is to call some Marshal method that will actually return a ready-to-use formatted instance of s2. Some code again to help the understanding.

```
    s2 temp = Marshal<s2>.CrateEmpty();
    int i = temp._s1[2].i1;
```

I need this functionality to avoid creating in each of my structs a method to make this formatting stuff. In the code above, Marshal.CreateEmpty() should be able to instantiate s2._s1 as an array with 5 elements.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `SizeConst` is wrong, if the array have 5 elements then you want 5*8 aka `SizeConst = 0x28`. Your s1 structure size is of 8 bytes.

Comment: No @Prix, it's not. The definition of MarshalAs.SizeConst is the following: "Indicates the number of elements in the fixed-length array or the number of characters (not bytes) in a string to import.".

Comment: Fairly difficult to understand what this question is about.  The most "ready to use" version is certainly `new s2()`.  Conversion from the managed to the native layout normally happens at the last possible moment, a standard duty of the pinvoke marshaller.  Otherwise also exposed as Marshal.StructureToPtr().

Comment: @HansPassant Imagine I have a byte[] representing the data sent through a tcp connection, I want to have some high-level representation of that packet in my code. So the idea is to use Marshal.PtrToStructure to "convert" the byte[] to my custom structs.

Comment: I wouldn't have any problems with this if C# could allow fixed-size array of custom types, this is the root of all the problems I'm facing atm :(

Comment: Well, make it so.  You need to call GCHandle.Alloc + GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject to get the Ptr you need.  Nothing "ready to use", [write a generic method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936208/17034) so it works for any structure type T.  Using XML or something like Protobuf if it has to be binary is generally the more productive way to go about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Your solution solves the problem of marshaling a byte[] to a structure, but what about marshaling a structure to a byte[]? Before being ready to call Marshal.StructureToPtr I have to initialize the array in s2, dont I?

Comment: Just edited my comment above.